# I'm trying to use plotly to display the USA map in jupyter notebook, however I keep getting error whenever I call go.Figure function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly-python, choropleth

choromap2 = go.Figure(data = [data],layout=layout)

I am getting error at this point

Comment: Please read How to ask.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  
and Minimal Reproducible Example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: and include the full error traceback message